# Unable to create Adjacency List for an undirected Graph using C

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

I'm faced with a problem which I've been unable to tackle for quite some time.
I've been given a graph as follows,in a M x N matrix:

```
2 2
a b
a c
```

**Note**
I've interpreted the graph above as a matrix,only consisting of non-diagonal edges.

Here the first line represents values of M and N respectively.
The graph is only connected either along vertical,or adjacent direction,i.e.,up,down,left and right. diagonal edges not present.

In order to find the adjacency list of the graph(the desired output here):

```
a-b-c
b-a-c
c-a-b
```

Steps followed by me in the code:

1.Read M x N matrix into a 2D array.

2.Created a list of unique vertices of the graph as Unode[arrmax].

3.For each element of the matrix,if the character matches with an element of the unique vertices list,I've called the modify Adjacency List procedure that searches the neighbours of the concerned matrix vertex and populates/appends to the the Adjacency list if distinct nodes are found.

4. It takes as arguments, i,j,M,N,AdjList,number of elements in the list and makes the changes.

5.I've kept the list of nodes to be global for easy modification.

6.Next I intend to use the adjacency list produced to use in DFS procedure and find the DFS forest.

**The Problem statement:**

> the input consists of  a grid of size M X N. Each cell in the grid
>   contain a lower case letter of the English alphabet.In a natural way,
>   the cells are of two types: boundary cells and internal cells. Each
>   internal cell in the grid has four neighbours in one of the left,
>   right, top, down directions. A string of characters can be formed by
>   starting at any cell and traversing the grid through the neighbours.
>   You have to print all the possible strings subject to the following
>   constraints:
>
> ```
> **No two characters in a string can be same 
> **No two strings can be same in the final output 
> **The strings should be printed in alphabetically sorted order.
> ```

```
INPUT: 

First line contains two integers M and N
Next M lines contains N space separated characters each

OUTPUT:

Print all possible strings in sorted order and obeying the above constraints.

INPUT SIZE:

1 <= M, N <= 20

SAMPLE INPUT:

2 2
a b
a c

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

a ab abc ac acb b ba bc bca c ca cb cba
```

**[UPDATE]:**
Completely redesigned the code,used structures for the graph nodes,and one for handling indices.
Yet the result I'm getting:

```
a--b-a
b--a
a
c--a
```

My code[Relevant Portion]:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define ADJMAX 20
#define arrmax 400

typedef struct uniq_node{
    char ch;
    char AdjList[ADJMAX];
    int numofelem;
    int visited;
}unode;

unode Ulist[arrmax];
int uniq_tot=0;

typedef struct index
{
    int i,j;
}Ind;

Ind indx;

int charcomp(char sch,char arr[],int arrlim);
void adjModify(unode*,char*,int,int,Ind);
int chIndex(int,int,int,int);

int main(void) {
    int mvar,nvar;
    char str[15],*token;
    long integer;

    /*To scan the values of M & N*/
    scanf("%d %d\n",&mvar,&nvar);
    int iter,iterv,jterv;

    /*To create the character matrix of M x N*/
    char cmat[mvar][nvar];


    /*Initializing the unique nodes list*/


    /*To read-in the matrix from the stdin:-A LOT OF HARD WORK*/
    for(iterv=0;iterv<mvar;iterv++)
    {
            fgets(str,50,stdin);
            jterv=0;
            token=strtok(str," ");
            while(token)
            {
                    /*Assigning value to the character matrix*/
                    cmat[iterv][jterv]=*token;
                    /*Code to populate the list of unique elements*/
                    if(charcomp(*token,Ulist[uniq_tot].AdjList,uniq_tot)==3)
                    {
                        Ulist[uniq_tot].ch=*token;
                        uniq_tot++;
                        Ulist[uniq_tot].numofelem=1;
                        Ulist[uniq_tot].AdjList[0]=*token;
                        //Ulist[uniq_tot].visited=0;
                    }
                    jterv++;
                    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
    }
    /*To populate the adjacency lists */
    char ch;
    for(iterv=0;iterv<mvar;iterv++)
    {
        for(jterv=0;jterv<nvar;jterv++)
        {
            ch=cmat[iterv][jterv];
            indx.i=iterv;
            indx.j=jterv;
            for(iter=0;iter<uniq_tot;iter++)
            { 
                if(ch==Ulist[iter].ch)
                break;
            }
            adjModify(&Ulist[iter],(char*)cmat,mvar,nvar,indx); 
        }
    }


    /*for(iter=0;iter<uniq_tot;iter++)
    {
        printf("%c",Ulist[iter].ch);
            printf("\n%s\n",Ulist[iter].AdjList);
        for(iterv=0;iterv<Ulist[iter].numofelem;iterv++)
        {
            printf("-%c",Ulist[iter].AdjList[iterv]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }*/

    return 0;
}

int chIndex(int i,int j,int mvar,int nvar)
{
    return (i>=0 && i<mvar && j>=0 && j<nvar);
}

void adjModify(unode* Unode,char* mat,int mvar,int nvar,Ind mind)
{
    int idum,jdum;
    if(chIndex(mind.i,mind.j-1,mvar,nvar))
        {
            idum=mind.i;
            jdum=mind.j-1;
            if(charcomp(*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum),Unode->AdjList,Unode->numofelem)==3)
                {
                    ++Unode->numofelem;
                Unode->AdjList[Unode->numofelem]=*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum);
                printf("\nI'm here in coord:(%d,%d), with element: %c, and AdjList: %s for character: %c",idum,jdum,*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum),Unode->AdjList,Unode->ch);
                }
        }
    if(chIndex(mind.i,mind.j+1,mvar,nvar))
        {
            idum=mind.i;
            jdum=mind.j+1;
            if(charcomp(*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum),Unode->AdjList,Unode->numofelem)==3)
                {
                    ++Unode->numofelem;
                Unode->AdjList[Unode->numofelem]=*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum);
                printf("\nI'm here in coord:(%d,%d), with element: %c, and AdjList: %s for character: %c",idum,jdum,*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum),Unode->AdjList,Unode->ch);
                }
        }
    if(chIndex(mind.i-1,mind.j,mvar,nvar))
        {
            idum=mind.i-1;
            jdum=mind.j;
            if(charcomp(*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum),Unode->AdjList,Unode->numofelem)==3)
                {
                    ++Unode->numofelem;
                Unode->AdjList[Unode->numofelem]=*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum);
                printf("\nI'm here in coord:(%d,%d), with element: %c, and AdjList: %s for character: %c",idum,jdum,*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum),Unode->AdjList,Unode->ch);
                }
        }
    if(chIndex(mind.i+1,mind.j,mvar,nvar))
        {
            idum=mind.i+1;
            jdum=mind.j;
            if(charcomp(*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum),Unode->AdjList,Unode->numofelem)==3)
                {
                    ++Unode->numofelem;
                Unode->AdjList[Unode->numofelem]=*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum);
                printf("\nI'm here in coord:(%d,%d), with element: %c, and AdjList: %s for character: %c",idum,jdum,*(mat+idum*nvar+jdum),Unode->AdjList,Unode->ch);
                }
        }
}

/*Comparison routine*/
int charcomp(char fchar,char arr[],int ucindex)
{
    int ivar;
    for(ivar=0;ivar<ucindex;ivar++)
    {
        if(arr[ivar]==fchar)
            return;
    }

        return 3;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the matrix? 2 2 a b a c doesn't look like a matrix to me. What does this represent? This looks like an awful lot of code to create a simple graph. You also say it's unidirectional, so why do your links look like they are directional?

Comment: 2 2 represents M and N respectively. And since No._of_edges/2=no. of unique vertices,thus I've treated it to be undirected. Also,for repetitive nodes I've used the same adjacency list.

Comment: When you say adjacency matrix I expect something like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix I don't know how to interpret yours.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't explicit,but I intend to create an adjacency list. That's an adjacency matrix representation,which I didn't use as I found the algorithm for DFS more convenient to code for Adj List..Also,I think my comparison routine is flawed,and/or somewhere the empty spaces are creeping into the Adj list,a fresh pair of eyes I believe will do the trick :-)

Comment: No problem, One more thing, is the input to this "a->b->c b->a->c c->a->b" and you're trying to parse that exact text? Do the arrows imply a directionality?

Comment: a->b->c; b->a->c; c->a->b; This is the desired output that I wish for my program to produce. And directionality is not implied,simply a connection or link only.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd like to help but I still don't follow how you get from your input to your output. Can you find an example you are trying to replicate?

Comment: I've updated the desription,see if it makes more sense. An example is difficult, but I'll try to find one.

Comment: The issue I'm having is if I interpret your matrix, I would personally come up with the graph "a-a-b a-b-c b-c-a c-a-a" or  "a adjacent to b; b adjacent to a,c; c adjacent to a,b"

Comment: I've treated the repeated elements as having the same adjacency list and not as distict elements. Also,the diagonal edges are not permitted. Hence instead of b-a-c, a-a-b, a-a-c, c-a-b it should have been a-b-c, b-a-c, c-a-b

Comment: If diagonal elements aren't permitted how can a connect to c?

Comment: As 'a' being a repeated node in the second row[i.e. row[1]] ,it will have the same Adjacency list as the 'a' node present above it. Also honestly, its just an approach which I've applied and believed it might work as it gave logically the right answers. It maybe wrong as well. If any recommendations/criticism in this sphere you might have,then certainly don't spare me.

Comment: Is there a certain theory you need to apply in the method, or can you achieve the goal any way you see fit? FYI Thanks for the problem statement, helped a lot.

Comment: No special theoretical technique I'm required to apply,probably,using Stack ADT in the recursive function I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can skip creating individual nodes for every element in the 2D array. Having the 2D array implies a structured connectivity. When it starts getting large, traversing all these elements may become cumbersome.

My recommended approach would be the following:

1. Scan of the matrix and pull unique nodes. i.e. start with a scan and have the simple list a,b,c (you'll need to sort them).
2. Create a struct for each unique node consisting the number of paths you currently have and an array of char arrays to store each one in. i.e. char** myArray={{a},{ab},{abc},{ac},{acb}} would be the one for a (This is of course unknown when you start).
3. Loop through your unique nodes, and one by one find the location in the 2D array. Don't save them, just go through them one by one and do a scan function to look for all their paths.
4. The scan function should be recursive so it can go as far as it needs to while checking every possible path (recursive will help you check every direction at every node you traverse). Keep track of where you've been, and at ever step check that you have not already encountered that character.
5. When you can't go any further, make sure the string has not already been included, if it has continue to the next path, if not add it to the list.

Comment: Of course this doesn't help if part of the goal is to create and use the adjacency list.

Comment: Alright,so recursive scan function,which I'll be implementing as DFS,must process each of the unique nodes once,i.e.,must run the DFS-visit(i,j) method starting with the indices of the first unique node,then second..? should I collect the strings at each step by capturing the state of the stack or only at the end of the procedure? And one more thing,I've had problem in manipulating char of chars that too for storing strings built out of the path traversed. Any strategy/code there?  And truly,thank you so much for your help :-) truly grateful,will upvote when I've gained sufficient reputation.

Comment: For the starting location, I like to have the unique char array first. Then you search through the 2-D array looking for all instances of that unique char. You don't need to store all these indices at once, just start the search there when you find each one. Then in the search recursively in every direction. You need to store the path as you go, since (1) every step you take you need to check that you haven't hit that char already (2) once you do hit a char you've reached you check you don't already have that string. If you don't have that string save it, if you do don't and continue.

Comment: For manipulating char arrays, allocate one that has a size matching the number of unique chars (since you can't have the same char in the array more than once). Re-use this char array for the searching to store your current path (removing the last array in each return of the recursive function). After you've found a path and want to store it, allocate another array of the size you need to store and add it to a list of char pointers for that unique node's structure.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code in c++ without any library that can work in c but you just have to use in c printf instead of cout and instead of class use struct that's all. I also write code for breadth first traversal see below.
and include the header file also

```
// #include <stdio.h>
//#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream
using namespace std;
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;

    Node(int data) {
        this->data=data;
        this->next=NULL;
       // cout<<"from node file"<<endl;
    }


};



class Queue {
    Node * head;
    Node * tail;
    int length;

    public:
        Queue() {
            head=NULL;
            tail=NULL;
            length=0;
        }

        bool isEmpty() {
            return length==0;
        }

        int size() {
            return length;
        }

        int front() {
            if(head==NULL) {
                cout<<"Empty Queue"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
            return head->data;
        }

        void enqueue(int element) {
            Node *  newNode =new Node(element);
            if(head==NULL) {
                head=newNode;
                tail=newNode;
            }else{
                tail->next=newNode;
                tail=newNode;
            }
            length++;
        }

        int dequeue() {
            if(head==NULL) {
                cout<<"Empty queue"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
            int output= head->data;
            Node * temp=head;
            head=head->next;
            temp->next=NULL;
            delete temp;
            length--;
            return output;
        }
};

class AdjList{
public:
    Node * head;
    AdjList() {
            head=NULL;
             //cout<<"from adlist"<<endl;
    }

    void add (int data) {
        Node * newNode=new Node(data);
        if(head==NULL) {
                head=newNode;
        }else {
                Node* temp=head;
                while(temp->next!=NULL) {

                    temp=temp->next;
                }
                temp->next=newNode;
        }
    }

};

class Graph{
public:
    int v;
    AdjList* adjList;


        Graph(int v) {
            this->v=v;
            adjList=new AdjList[v];
        }

        void addEdge(int src, int dest) {
                adjList[src].add(dest);
                ///for bidrectional add below code
                //adjList[dest].add(src);
        }



    void print(){
        for(int i=0;i<v;i++){
            Node *temp = adjList[i].head;
            cout << i << " -> ";
            while(temp != NULL)
            {
                cout << temp->data << " ";
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

     void bfs(int src) {
        // using a queue also in this file how to add queue structure
        Queue q;
        bool* visited=new bool [v]{0};
        q.enqueue(src);
        visited[src]=true;
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            int node= q.front();
            cout<<node<<"  ";
            q.dequeue();
            Node *temp = adjList[node].head;
            while(temp!=NULL){
                if(!visited[temp->data]) {
                        q.enqueue(temp->data);
                        visited[temp->data]=true;
                }
               // cout<<"data "<<temp->data;
                temp=temp->next;
             /// how to traverse
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(){

   Graph g(6);

       g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 3);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.addEdge(3,4);
   g.addEdge(4,5);

 g.bfs(0);

  // g.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: prefer explaining and answering the question precisely instead of giving a full code for generic case. Thanks